# Infix notation to postfix notation using stack

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I am trying to convert infix notation to postfix notation using stack. I have written the following code but it is giving me error:

```
/Users/apple/Desktop/infix.c|49|error: expected expression
```

and I am unable to find the error. Please help me to correct this code.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <ctype.h>

 #define MAX 100

 char st[MAX];
 int top = -1;

 void push(char st[],char);
 char pop(char st[]);
 void InfixtoPostfix(char source[],char target[]);
 int getPriority(char);

 int main(){
    char infix[100],postfix[100];
    printf("enter any infix expression");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(infix);
    strcpy(postfix,"");
    InfixtoPostfix(infix,postfix);
    printf("\nthe corresponding postfix expression is:");
    puts(postfix);
    return 0;
}
void InfixtoPostfix(char source[],char target[]){
    int i=0,j=0;
    char temp;
    strcpy(target,"");
    while(source[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(source[i]=='(')
        {
            push(st,source[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else if(source[i]==')')
        {
            while((top!=-1)&&(st[top]!='('))
            {
                target[j]=pop(st);
                j++;
            }
            if(top==-1)
            {
                printf("\nincorrect syntax");
                exit(1);
            }
            temp=pop(st);
            i++;
            else if((isdigit(source[i]))||(isalpha(source[i]))
            {
                target[j]=source[i];
                j++;
                i++;
            }
            else if(source[i]=='+'||source[i]=='-  '||source[i]=='*'||source[i]='/'||source[i]=='%d')
            {
                while((top!=-1)&&(st[top]!='(')&&(getPriority(st[top])>getPriority(source[i])))
                {
                    target[j]=target[i];
                    i++;
                }
                push(st,source[i]);
                i++;
            }
            else{
                printf("\nincorrect expression");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        while((top!=-1)&&(st[top]!='('))
        {
            target[j]=pop(st);
            j++;
        }
        target[j]='\0';

    }
}
int getPriority(char op)
{
    if(op=='/'||op=='*'||op=='%'||op=='%')
    return 1;
    else if(op=='+'||op=='-')
    return 0;
}
void push(char st[],char val)
{
    if(top==MAX-1)
        printf("overflow");
    else{
        top++;
        st[top]=val;
    }
}
char pop(char st[])
{
    char val=' ';
    if(top==-1)
        printf("underflow");
    else{
        val=st[top];
        top--;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Let's start with "What line is line 49?"

Comment: at least indent the code properly.

Answer (score 1):

Many problems, the most important one being

```
else if((isdigit(source[i]))||(isalpha(source[i]))
```

lacks a closing parentheses, your coding style makes it difficult to notice

```
else if ((isdigit(source[i]) != 0) || (isalpha(source[i]) != 0))
```

And don't use `gets()` it's deprecated, in your case

```
fgets(infix, sizeof(infix), stdin);
```

would work, and will have the benefit of preventing a buffer overflow.

Comment: I hadn't spotted the missing `)`, but there's a bigger problem on the line than that — the `else` isn't preceded by the body of an `if` and is therefore invalid.

Answer (score 1):

While there are so many issues in the code, 
this one here is the most horror:

```
if(top==-1)
{
    printf("\n incorrect syntex");
    exit(1);
}
temp=pop(st);
i++;
else if((isdigit(source[i]))||(isalpha(source[i]))
{
   target[j]=source[i];
   j++;
   i++;
}
```

No, you are not doing that right. FWIK, C doesn't allow this:

```
if()
{
    //some code
}
//some code
else{
    //some code
}
```

- The other issue being:
  `else if((isdigit(source[i]) )||(isalpha(source[i]))`. I would prefer it to be,
  `else if( (0 != isdigit(source[i])) || (0 != isalpha(source[i])) )`
  Or as suggested by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) in a comment below:  even better if you use `if (isalnum(source[i]))` since it checks for all alphanumeric.
- Is it only me who finds the code not so readable?
  Instead of `if(op=='/'||op=='*'||op=='%'||op=='%')` I would prefer
  `if((op == '/')||(op == '*')||(op == '%'))` in terms of readability.

Comment: Speaking personally, I'd rather see: `if (op == '/' || op == '*' || op == '%')` with spaces around the binary operator `==`, a space after the `if` and no superfluous parentheses, and no double test of `%`.  And it is conventional to use the 'boolean' test operators more or less as in the question: `if (isdigit(source[i]) || isalpha(source[i]))` thus — though it is better to use `if (isalnum(source[i]))` which tests for an alphanumeric all in one go.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, using `if (isalnum(source[i]))` makes sense. Great point.